# XAML Apply A Style to Multiple ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this XAML, which currently works. I want to add a second `ListBox` that will have the same `Style` as the first. I'd like to define a `Style` that gets applied to both rather than repeating all the XAML. I've tried a `<style></style>` tag in `Windows.Resources` but it did not know what `ListBox.GroupStyle` was. I tried a `ListBox.GroupStyle`, but it did not know what the `TargetType` parameter was. I'm not sure what I should be searching for to figure this out. Most of the examples deal with styling a single ListBox and do it directly in the XAML.

```
<Grid Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
           Padding="0,0,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemList}">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                  <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                  </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Margin="5 5 0 0"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Path=ActionLabel}"
          Margin="10" Click="ActionButton_Click"/>
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel"
          Margin="10" Click="CloseButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: <ListBox.GroupStyle> is just markup representing a property of a ListBox, not a type or object. Of course you cannot instantiate a property (in a resource dictionary or anywhere else). Try instantiating a <GroupStyle> in the resource dictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `Style` for the `ListBox` in the `Window.Resources`. I don't know if your attempts raised some errors, but you *really* can carry to the `Style` all the common properties.
Any `ListBox` that must take that `Style` has only to set its `Style` property.

Here is a possible example:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="MyListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,10,10"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False">
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </Expander>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="LB1"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Source1}"
           Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyListBoxStyle}"/>

  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="LB2"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Source2}"
           Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyListBoxStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

I left the `ItemsSource` property out of the `Style` because I suppose that the two `ListBoxes` have 2 different sources, but if they have the same one, you can add a `Setter` in the `Style` like this:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=MySingleSource}"/>
```